# PostgreSQL Replication without DELETE , DROP queries

Tags: postgresql, backup, replication, standby

i just configured a hot standby server in order to replicate my PostgreSQL database immediately . It works perfectly , but i want to disallow [DELETE , Truncate , DROP etc..] queries from replication so i can have a live backup which avoid data loss.

What do you propose guys ?

I tried delayed replication but it delay all queries (CREATE, INSERT ,UPDATE ..) which can't be useful to me

Comment: Use logical replication: https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/logical-replication-publication.html